# What is type of object in 'onclick' handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg

I'm adding images into 'svg' object with JavaScript and then assign 'onclick' event handler for each of them:

```
var svgMap = $("#map").get(0);
$($('polygon'), svgMap)
        .bind('click', tileClicked2)
```

Here '#map' is my svg-object.

In my event handler I can work with object clicked:

```
    function tileClicked2(evt) {
        $(this).attr('fill', 'black');
    }
```

But what is 'evt' parameter that is passed into handler? I've tried to investigate if it can be useful, but can't find anything...

Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried calling `console.log` with it?

Comment: As @Epeli said, in this case it is the jQuery  event object. For general reference, have a look here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html

Comment: Did you think to check [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com)?

Comment: 2icktoofay: as I told I did investigate... Also, I looked in debugger in watch view what it contains, but didn't find out what is that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case it is jQuery Event object

http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/